# Docker run environment variable regex / wildcard

Tags: docker, regex

On my host machine I run the following:

```
export test_1="Hello"
export test_2="There"
```

Starting Docker container:

```
docker run -it -e test* centos
```

The env variables are not available in the container.
Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to filter your environment variables like

```
env | grep ^test > env.list
```

and then use [env-file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) docker option to pass all variables at once:

```
docker run -it --env-file env.list centos
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, gets the job done. thanks!